# Godaddy not Detecting button click event Error CS1601

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, buttonclick

some Button click events are not detecting in GoDaddy.

here is the code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditUserprofile.aspx.cs" Inherits="RechargeProfits.EditUserprofile" MasterPageFile="Recharge_profts.master"  %>

<asp:Content ID="home_page" ContentPlaceHolderId="inner_page_data_single_column" runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="usual row">
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="button small" runat="server" 
        Text="Logout" onclick="Button1_Click" ></asp:Button>
</div>
```

Here is my back end code

```
namespace RechargeProfits
{
public partial class EditUserprofile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogOut();
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a godaddy issue? Does the code work locally? Are there any errors thrown? What results do you get? Please revise your question to help us answer it

Comment: I know GoDaddy have a funny rep, but really? The problem is almost certainly the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the version of the .NET framework that's supported / installed on your GoDaddy server, vs. what you're using locally.

CS1601 is a compiler error that has to do with invalid argument types.  If you are not getting that error locally, and are getting it on the hosting server, it's very, very likely that they are running a different version of the framework.